# How can i write the code to do "When i click cancel in options windows , that field will hide."

Tags: field, lotus-notes, lotusscript

I have a field in the Notes document , the field name is "reason".
if i click a button,will show a options windows , and the field will show out.
now i need to know how can i write the code to do "when i click cancel in options windows , that field will hide.".
the options windows is PROMPT_OKCANCELLIST.
the following codes is i write in the button:

```
If uipr.FieldGetText("TRACK_MARK") = "" Then
    Call uipr.FieldSetText("TRACK_MARK" , "Y")
End If
askme = ws.prompt(PROMPT_OKCANCELLIST,"Track Reason","Please choose reason..." , data(0) , data())
If askme = "" Then
    If uipr.FieldGetText("TRACK_MARK") = "Y" Then
        Call uipr.FieldSetText("TRACK_MARK" ,"")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Sorry, the posted code does not relate to your question regarding a "reason"- field... Please clarify... If you want to show / hide a field you need to define a hide- when- formula that defines the condition and call a uipr.Refresh() after changing the condition...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Form with the Reason field, you will need to select the paragraph you wish to hide, then in the Properties box, select **Hide paragraph if formula is true**, and enter `TRACK_MARK="Y"` :

[image]

This will hide the paragraph once TRACK_MARK is set to "Y".